# Python threading - Hanging on Exit

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've been working my way through learning python and in this test program I'm writing, I'd like to create a thread for a periodic call to some update function. I thought about using the `after()` method but from my understanding, that doesn't operate "in the background" and it just places those instructions into the que for execution. Realistically for what I'm trying to do, it's probably fine to use `after` but I'd like to make a thread just so I don't have to worry about over-burdening the primary process (also trying to understand better how threading works).

I'm using tkinter to make a window and then within that there are two labels. In this example they're pretty simple but in the larger program I'm making, the `var_value` object of the `info` class gets updated externally. The idea is that I'll have the second function `upd_dsply` to refresh the string vars (and as a result the label gets updated).

```
"""
threading test
"""

#-----------------------------imports
import tkinter as tk                    #tkinter include for UI
import time
import threading as thrd
import datetime as dt

#-----------------------------variables
run_thrd = True             #boolean for running the dash update thread
refresh_rate = .067         #time interval for screen refresh

class data_info:
    def __init__(self, var_value, var_val_str):
        self.var_value = var_value        #data label
        self.var_val_str = var_val_str    #data value

info = []
info.append(data_info(1200, None))        #value 1
info.append(data_info(160, None))         #value 2
info_indx_size = len(info)                #number of data vars to keep track of

#-----------------------------support functions
def upd_strvar(indx):
    data = info[indx].var_value           #data array value  
    info[indx].var_val_str.set(str(data)) #set strVar value     

def upd_dsply():
    while run_thrd:                     #as long as the window is open, run thread
        print('display updated at time ', dt.datetime.now())
        for i in range(info_indx_size):             #cycle through all the entires of disp_data
            #TODO: calling the below causes issues. It never really "releases" the terminal
            #upd_strvar(i)                           #update label stringvar
            pass
        time.sleep(refresh_rate)

#-----------------------------class for main window
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #---------------------window settings/info
        self.title("Test Dash")
        self.geometry("400x400")                #window size
        self.maxsize(400,400)                   #set max size
        self.resizable(False,False)             #fixed size

        #----init stringvar for data labels
        for i in range(info_indx_size):                     #loop through array
            info[i].var_val_str = tk.StringVar(self, '')    #and assign as a strvar
            upd_strvar(i)

        #----data labels
        #label 1
        lbl1 = tk.Label(self)                            #create label
        lbl1.config(textvariable=info[0].var_val_str)    #bind label to stringvar
        lbl1.config(font=("Sans-Serif",35))              #format the label
        lbl1.config(anchor="e")     
        lbl1.place(x=50,y=50)
        
        #label 2
        lbl2 = tk.Label(self)
        lbl2.config(textvariable=info[1].var_val_str)
        lbl2.config(font=("Sans-Serif",35))
        lbl2.config(anchor="e")      
        lbl2.place(x=50,y=200)

        #----Display refresh
        #attempt 2:
        thrd.Timer(refresh_rate, upd_dsply).start() #threading instance to update display params every refresh time period
    #support classes/functions
#end of main window class

#attempt 1: This doesn't work because it is run before "var_val_str" is assigned a strvar
#thrd.Timer(refresh_rate, upd_dsply).start() #threading instance to update display params every refresh time period

#-----------------------------main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow()
    app.mainloop()

run_thrd = False                                    #set threading run flag to false to stop all threads
```

Couple of things I'm trying to do and observations:

- I use the `run_thrd` variable as a condition for the while loop within `upd_dsply`. Once the main window is closed, it is set to false and effectively stops the while condition in the thread. Without this it'll just run on indefinitely. This in itself makes sense but I'm not sure if there's a "neater" way to do this and may be causing issues elsewhere.
- Testing with just the `print` statement works fine, as expected. This leads me to believe I'm correctly entering the thread and it's printing out at the expected interval.
- If I incorporate (uncomment) the `upd_strvar(i)` line in the `upd_dsply` function and call the `thrd.Timer(...).start()` directly before the call for the main window (at the bottom, commented as "attempt 1") it doesn't successfully run. This in itself makes sense; I'm initializing the variable within the class as a `None` type and then within the `MainWindow` I re-assign them as string vars. I was having issues with referencing the container (in this case, just the `self` item) outside of the main window which is why I did this.
- If I start the thread at the end of the main window definition (at the bottom, commented as "attempt 2") it will successfully run and prints to the terminal. This leads me to believe that the thread is being created and running appropriately.

The issue is however, that when closing out of the program, the terminal is never fully "released". If i re-comment out the `upd_strvar(i)` line in the `upd_dsply` function, closing out the main window will release the terminal and prompt for new input. With the function still included, no new print statements are put out to the terminal but there's also no ability to enter in new commands.

This makes me think that how I'm exiting the thread is the issue here. I'm wondering if using the `run_thrd` variable as a condition for the while statement in `upd_dsply` is exiting the while statement but the inner for loop is still executing (and is why the terminal is never "available" after exiting the program).

Just as a summary:

- Still figuring this python thing out
- Attempting to create a thread
- Exiting the program doesn't release the terminal so I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You can't do any tkinter calls from a secondary thread, including updating a StringVar.

Comment: Try using `timer = thrd.Timer(...)`, `timer.daemon = True`, `timer.start()`. That way when the main thread exists, the timer thread if forced to exist. Also the statement about *"over-burdening the primary process"* doesn't make sense in this context because of the GIL. For the `.after` approach, ook at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/11106801).

Comment: @TheLizzard that's a great piece of information on the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), thanks. I hadn't come across that yet. I see (just googling around) that python has/had done away with the GIL, but am i understanding it correctly that tkinter is still affected because it's a single-threaded process?

I had tried using the `daemon=true` via pass arguments in defining the timer but that was having issues for some reason. I'll try using the above.

I already had a working solution using `after` actually referencing your link as well! Just was trying to learn more about python workings.

Comment: @jungle_jim Passing in `daemon=True` inside the `Timer(...)` will call your `upd_dsply` methods with `daemon=True` instead of making the thread daemonic (that's why I suggested the `.daemon = True`). You can check that by reading the 15 lines of actual code from python's [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c42347d025b29e993a12925a3ddf58c0c9bb7f7b/Lib/threading.py#L1401). CPython (the one you probably have) still has a GIL. The `tkinter` developers have tried to make `tkinter` thread-safe but haven't accounted for a lot of the edge cases so avoid threads with `tkinter`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I see that now after some more reading. I hadn't chased it down at the time and just assumed it would be a **kwarg. I had found the same about tkinter, so i was hesitant about threading but it seemed simple enough to try (with minimal threat of consequence). Given the GIL though there's no gains so that makes it an easy decision for just using `after`. Also TIL on getting into the weeds on how python is implemented.....thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case to use to learn to understand threading. Tk GUIs (and most GUI systems) are inherently single-threaded; you can spawn off threads to do work that is later passed back to the UI thread for display, but simultaneously updating the UI from multiple threads is typically unsafe, useless, or both (and even if it does work for specific GUI libraries, it means locking around all the inter-thread communication just to avoid corrupting the event loop's queue, which slows things down).

The reason you *think* you need threading is because you used an infinite loop with no voluntary releases back to the event loop and to add insult to injury, included a `time.sleep` in it, so if you invoked it within the UI thread:

1. The event loop *never* gets to process any queued work (because it never gets control back), and
2. It can't even do it when nothing else is happening, the infinite task is sleeping without handling control back to the loop.

What you really want is something like this:

```
def upd_dsply():
    print('display updated at time ', dt.datetime.now())
    for i in range(info_indx_size):
        upd_strvar(i)
    if run_thrd:
        app.after(round(refresh_rate * 1000), upd_dsply)
```

Then change `thrd.Timer(refresh_rate, upd_dsply).start()` to `self.after(0, upd_dsply)` to initiate the first round of updates.

What that does is run *one* round of updates each time `upd_dsply` is called, and so long as `run_thrd` remains true, it schedules another round of updates `refresh_rate` seconds later (`time.sleep` takes the argument as floating point seconds, `after` takes it as integer milliseconds, thus the multiply and `round`).

Importantly, once it schedules the next update, it *finishes*, returning control to the event loop so it can update the UI, handle any other queued tasks, and eventually, run the next scheduled update. It avoids the problems that trying to modify the UI from multiple threads at once can cause, and it shouldn't have any meaningful impact on performance (the GIL means that any CPU-bound Python level work you might have done in the thread won't actually parallelize, and your code isn't doing any I/O, so there's no meaningful gain from parallelism available).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I had found that tkinter is not thread-safe but didn't realize that also extended to the stringVars it was relying on. As stated in the beginning, I had thought of `after` already. I didn't THINK I needed one thing in particular but was trying to understand one of the 18 different ways to skin the cat.

That aside, I'm missing something with your #1 and #2. Isn't the whole point of threading is to create a second parallel task? I hate `wait` or `sleep` or any "pause" as much as the next guy but don't see how that's immobilizing the main loop.

Comment: @jungle_jim: I was saying that it immobilizes the main loop *when* you use it without threading (which may have contributed to your decision to try threads over `.after` use). I may have been assuming too much here; if you had a design without an infinite loop or `time.sleep` usage when you were trying `.after`, then it might have been okay.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, understood on the implications of `sleep`. I had used it PURELY in the case of the threaded function to provide an interval. I had no issues implementing `after` with a given time period and no use of sleep at all. Realistically, given the processor speed, not creating a thread for my "update my strVars" part of the code wouldn't be an issue anyway. Plus i had been unaware of the GIL as you and others have pointed out, so it's been more reading!